# Append mutliple json requests to one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have multiple json requests with same information but in different location which is differentiate by polygons. Example of url : `www.dummy.com/whatever?type=fruit&polygon=1,1;2,2`. I have about 20 requests on same `fruit` but different `polygon`.

My goal is to append all of the same fruits regardless any location. The url request is in JSON format.

I created a dictionary where it store all of the URLs and I constructed them this way :

```
urlDict['fruit']+polygonsDict[coords]
```

The dictionary looks like this:

```
urlDict = {
  'fruit': 'www.dummy.com/whatever?type=fruit&polygon=',
  'animal': 'www.dummy.com/whatever?type=animal&polygon=',
  'colour': 'www.dummy.com/whatever?type=colour&polygon='
}

polygonsDict = {
  0:'1,1;2,2',
  1:'3,3;4,4',
  2:'5,5;6,6'}
```

Now, I want to loop over all `fruit` url and append them to a dataframe. Since the response is in JSON, I want to use python `explode` to expand the `dict` to `DataFrame` which takes `list` as value.

Here is my code :

```
for idx, polygon in polygonsDict.items():
    url = urlDict['fruit']+polygonsDict[coords]
    print(url) #www.dummy.com/whatever?type=fruit&polygon=blahblah

    try :
        raw = req.get(url).json()

        fruits_raw = [raw] #convert the result to list

        fruits_df = pd.DataFrame(fruits_raw).explode('fieldname').reset_index(drop=True)
        print(fruits_df)

    except KeyError:
        print("No fruit in this location.")
```

The code is created individual dataframe for every polygon. I want it to append and produce ONE dataframe about `fruit` regardless the `polygon`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If each DataFrame has identical columns, you can insert each one into a list and pass the list of frames into [`pandas.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to merge them into a single DataFrame.

Comment: I should do this outside of loop? @gallen

Comment: Inside the loop, add each frame to a list that is declared before the loop. After the loop, perform the `concat()` call on that list of frames, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formalizing my comments as an answer. Using [`pandas.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) you can merge a list of DataFrames into a single one.

```
import pandas as pd

frames = []
for idx, polygon in polygonsDict.items():
    url = urlDict['fruit']+polygonsDict[coords]
    print(url) #www.dummy.com/whatever?type=fruit&polygon=blahblah

    try :
        raw = req.get(url).json()

        fruits_raw = [raw] #convert the result to list

        fruits_df = pd.DataFrame(fruits_raw).explode('fieldname').reset_index(drop=True)
        print(fruits_df)

        # Add the frame to the list
        frames.append(fruits_df)

    except KeyError:
        print("No fruit in this location.")

# Combine the list of DataFrames into a single DataFrame
single = pd.concat(frames)
print(single)
```